# While() em leitura por linha em arquivo .CSV

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Bom dia,

tenho as seguintes estruturas:

```
typedef struct celCidade *apontadorCidade;
typedef struct celEstado *apontadorEstado;

typedef struct{

    char nome[100];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    int qtdCidades;
    float idh;
    apontadorEstado proxEstado;
    apontadorCidade Arv;

}celEstado;

typedef struct{

     char nomeCidade[100];
     char nomeEstado[100];
     int populacao;
     int beneficiarios;
     float idhm;
     apontadorCidade esq;
     apontadorCidade dir;

 }celCidade;
```

Cada campo dessa estrutura tem seus dados contidos em um arquivo .csv, onde cada cidade deverá estar associada a seu devido estado, então a triagem deve ser feita durante a leitura dos dados com seus devidos *if's* e *else's* e por se tratar de um arquivo com uma quantidade considerável de dados, gostaria de fazer a leitura através de um `while()`, pois acho mais prático, onde a condição de parada seria quando não tiver mais dados a serem lidos.

Até agora estou na estaca zero.

```
void carregaArquivo(FILE *arquivo){

    arquivo = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    if(arquivo != NULL){
        printf("Arquivo lido com sucesso!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Erro ao carregar o arquivo!\n");
    }


}
```

Eis o problema: não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer essa leitura, já li sobre `fscanf()`, `fgets()` e outras formas que posso utilizar para ler esses dados, porém gostaria de saber:

1. Qual a melhor função para ler **linhas** de um arquivo CSV
2. Como identificar a ordem dos campos no programa
3. Qual seria a condição de parada do `while()`?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Você sabe ler um arquivo .txt?

Comment: Não, é a mesma coisa em csv?

Comment: Mesma coisa, mas tem várias maneiras para ler. Recomendo pesquisar as funções fscanf ou fread para leitura do arquivo. A condição de parada do while pode verificar se encontrou o fim do arquivo while (fscanf()!=EOF)  ele continua lendo. Tem que ver o que você precisa fazer, para ter uma ideia de como fica melhor para realizar essa leitura

Comment: "Como identificar a ordem dos campos no programa": você precisa saber o que está lendo, normalmente isto significa saber quais campos e em que ordem eles estarão no arquivo sendo lido. "Qual seria a condição de parada do while()": teste por EOF a cada leitura.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou procurar saber mais sobre EOF e atualizado a pergunta qualquer coisa

Comment: melhor função para ler por linha é "fgets"; depois tem a análises dos campos de uma linha csv; esta tarefa pode não ser trivial, dependendo dos formatos aceitos (por exemplo, pode ter campos delimitados por aspas ?" etc); se por para uso profissional (e não como exercício de faculdade) provavelmente o mais adequado é procurar alguma lib já pronta para essa tarefa (google "csv c library")

Comment: obrigado pela dica zentrunix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começando pelas suas perguntas:

> Qual a melhor função para ler linhas de um arquivo CSV

Cada caso é um caso e depende sempre da estrutura que os seus dados tem, validações que tem de ser aplicadas, entre outros fatores.

> Como identificar a ordem dos campos no programa

Regra geral você sabe qual o arquivo que está a ler e qual a estrutura e ordem de campos existe no mesmo. Com essa informação a leitura pode ser muito direta, com `fscanf` por exemplo(como irei exemplificar mais à frente), mas se não souber então complica drasticamente.

Quando não sabe, tem que ler linha a linha com `fgets` e *tokenizar* a entrada através do `;` com o `strtok` por exemplo, e tentar aplicar uma leitura de cada tipo no *token* até acertar numa que funcione. Ou ler todos os campos como strings que também não é o ideal.

> Qual seria a condição de parada do while()?

Depende do tipo de leitura que tem. Com `fscanf` a condição de paragem é baseada na quantidade de elementos lidos ou até utilizando `EOF` que corresponde ao fim do arquivo.

Se usar `fgets` a paragem é normalmente dada pelo retorno de `NULL` da função.

### Leitura com `fscanf`

Na minha ótica esta é a forma mais direta de ler, mas **implica que você saiba a estrutura exata do arquivo**.
Imagine que tem um csv com 3 inteiros por linha. Nesse caso bastaria-lhe o seguinte código para ler o arquivo até ao fim:

```
int valor1, valor2, valor3;

while(fscanf(arquivo_csv, "%d;%d;%d", &valor1, &valor2, &valor3) == 3){
    //fazer coisas com os 3 campos
}
```

No exemplo acima o `fscanf` já inclui os `;` que separam cada campo e os respetivos `%d` para cada inteiro. O `== 3` vai manter o `while` a executar enquanto for possível ler 3 elementos. Igualmente válido seria `while(fscanf(...) != EOF){`.

Esta solução irá funcionar perfeitamente mesmo se tiver campos que sejam do tipo `char` ou `double`(ajustando os parâmetros no `fscanf`), mas o problema começa quando precisa de ler strings. A leitura de string com `%s` lê apenas uma palavra e por isso se estiver a ler um nome completo, o `%s` vai apenas apanhar o primeiro nome, não lendo corretamente a linha. Mas mesmo nesse caso consegue contornar o problema trocando a leitura de `%s` para `%[^;]` que significa: ler até apanhar o próximo `;`.

O exemplo anterior lendo agora 1 string e 2 inteiros ficaria assim:

```
char valor1[50];
int valor2, valor3;

while(fscanf(arquivo_csv, "%[^;];%d;%d", valor1, &valor2, &valor3) == 3){
    //fazer coisas com os 3 campos
}
```

Para o seu exemplo precisa apenas de ajustar os campos necessários aos tipos que tem, sendo que **os ponteiros nunca poderão ser lidos e guardados diretamente no arquivo**. Em vez disso tem de guardar uma referência válida ao elemento, como um `id` ou `nome` que seja única, e construir o ponteiro com base nessa referência.

Apesar de tudo, esta leitura com `fscanf` é mais fácil de quebrar se o arquivo estiver mal formatado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! assim que chegar em casa irei testar!

Answer (score 1):

A partir das suas estruturas presumo que você quer criar uma lista ligada com nós "estados", cada qual apontando para uma árvore com nós "cidades".

Para implementar o programa completo eu precisaria saber um pouco como está formatado seu arquivo. Também preciso saber que tipo de árvore você quer criar para as cidades de um estado.

A sua questão faz referência a como ler um arquivo linha a linha e separar seus campos. As funções chave para esta tarefa são "fgets()" e "strtok()". O seguinte programa lê linhas no arquivo "input" e lista os campos, os quais se encontram separados pelo "DELIMITADOR".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINHA 1024
#define DELIMITADOR ","

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    // abre arquivo
    FILE* fp = fopen("input", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Falha ao abrir o arquivo");
        return(1);
    }

    // separa linhas
    char linha[MAX_LINHA];
    char *campo;
    while (fgets(linha, MAX_LINHA, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        printf("Linha: %s", linha);

        // separa tokens
        printf("Campos:\n");
        campo = strtok(linha, DELIMITADOR);
        while( campo != NULL ) 
        {
            printf( "--> %s\n", campo);
            campo = strtok(NULL, DELIMITADOR);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, nós estados ligados e cada um com sua árvore de cidades. Muito obrigado pela resposta, assim que chegar em casa irei testar!